How to see the process of a render
so i see some YouTuber rendering an image but when they render it I can see some little dots so I wonder show can I do that, I try to search it at google but I don't found any result.
This is the Example


All I can see is a certain amount of background noise so presumably the render is in the denoising phase. You can usually see the render progress in the top-left of the render window.

This is the raytracing noise, and visible only at low samples (and worsened by scene complexity, low light and complex shaders calculations like volumetrics). It is not a feature, most people work hard to get rid of this noise as much as possible. It is a byproduct of how raytracing functions. And though the longer a render computes the less noise you have, the amount of noise isn't really representative of render progress, especially these days when things like denoising exist. If you want something to guesstimate progress in raytraced rendering, looking at your render stats is way more informative:

Samples progress, elapsed time, last frame time if you render an animation, ...

If you don't see any noise in your render, it can be multiple things. Some of which:
Your render is too simple for noise to be significant. This is what the default cube looks like with just 10 samples:

Your hardware calculates samples too fast for you to notice the early noisy samples. Though it's a good "issue" to have, since it means less waiting. And also easy to identify by rotating your viewport around: it's fluid and capped at 1 sample, until you stop moving:

You are not using any ray tracing in your render. I.E. you are rendering with Eevee, the only ray tracing available in that render engine is optional and disabled by default. The workbench engine doesn't have any raytracing at all.
You have denoising enabled. By default, it is only enabled for final rendering and applied at the end of all samples. For viewport rendering, it is disabled by default, but otherwise it has the particularity of being applied as soon as the first sample, giving a mushy bur noise-free look at the first sample.
